# SQL trim wildcard pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, search, replace, wildcard

I have a quite large MySQL db table (posts) and in one field (post_text) there are a lot of old BB code that needs trimming.

This is one example of what i need to find:
`quote:1270ae936b`
(after : characters varies, always 10)

And replace with:
`quote:`

How do i do this in SQL command?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you want quote:1270ae936b to be replaced with quote?

Comment: Try SELECT SUBSTRING('post_text',1,5)

Comment: Yes! I want to replace quote:1270ae936b with quote:

But the 10 characters always varies and there are many like this.

Comment: Can you please exemplify more detailed with the SUBSTRING command? I'm a novice in SQL commands :)

Comment: Can you have more than one post:whatever in a single field?

Comment: A row/post can look like this: word word word [quote:<10-character-string>] word word word [quote:<a-different-10-character-string>] word word word

Comment: Even though the 10 strings vary, you will get the output as quote.

Comment: Substring(columnname, strtposition, noofchartodisplay). It works this way

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but logically it should work for you. check more about specific range of characters at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

**Test Query:**

```
//run it before update query
 SELECT post_text FROM posts WHERE post_text REGEXP 'quote:[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}';
```

**Main Query:**

```
    UPDATE posts
    SET post_text = 'quote:' 
    WHERE post_text REGEXP 'quote:[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}';
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :) But the rows contain a lot of text, not only: quote:<10-character-string>. Now all of the text in the post/row was replaced with quote:.
How do i preserve the rest ?

Comment: @Jannef you mean `quote:<10-character-string> morestringchar343` ? like this

Comment: A row/post can look like this: word word word [quote:<10-character-string>] word word word [quote:<a-different-10-character-string>] word word word

Comment: Hi again,
Is there a way to preserve all the other text in the row/post?
Thx in advance!